# How to disable hardware back button for a specific page only

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

i am having issue with how to disable the back-button hardware. i only want it to work on the homepage of my app and not other pages. it works well when you are on the homepage but also works on every other page that opens. i want users to be able to use the back button on all the pages except the homepage.
This is my code

```
`deactivateBackButton()
this.subscribe = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(666666,()=>{
if (this.constructor.name == "HomePage") {
if (window.confirm("Do you want to exit app")) {
navigator["app"].exitApp();
 }
}
});
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to implement double clicking back button twice to exit an acitivity

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

This is an implementation for pressing the back button twice to exit. If you want somewhat similar you can modify it as per your need.

Comment: I am using IONIC 5, i don't quite understabd the @overid part. what i just want is when users sign in i don't want them to be able to go back tot he sign in page again. This happens when they click the back button

Comment: My suggestion would be to finish the activity that you don't want the users to go back to. For instance, in your sign in activity, right after you call startActivity, call `finish()`. When the users hit the back button, they will not be able to go to the sign in activity because it has been killed off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simple way **Don't call super.onBackPressed()**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// super.onBackPressed();
// Not calling super, disables back button in current screen.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On other Pages:

```
activateBackButton()
    this.subscribe =  this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(666666,()=>{
          if (this.constructor.name != "HomePage") {
             // go back to previous page
          }
     });
  }
```

Comment: Let em try this. Thanks

Comment: Please Mark it as accepted answer so other can get help too.

Comment: It worked i have tried accepting it as anwser but the system won't allow me